# Change the width of an UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, width, uibarbuttonitem

How can I change the width of an `UIBarButtonItem` to 29px? The property width does not work and I don't want to create a `UIButton` and use the `initWithCustomView` because I want the square background to adjust to the navigation bar color.
I'm using the `initWithImage` to init the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Here is my button with a current width of 37px. I want to set to 29px.

[image: UIButton]

Comment: @MaxMacLeod The asker specifically doesn't want to use initWithCustomView...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you cant. If you want custom width you will need to use `initWithCustomView`

Comment: But why do they have the property width in the UIBarButtonItem class?

Comment: you can use it only if button in UIToolbar

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by dropping an image to the bar button item from the interface builder and changing the width of the custom view with this code:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView.frame;
frame.size.width = 141;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView.frame = frame;
```