# UIBarButtonItem like Facebook with Lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, uibarbuttonitem

How do you make a UIBarButtonItem like the one Facebook uses for their Navigation?  I've tried to search and create an image, but I just can't get it to look right.  Here's an example of the button I'm trying to make: [Change the width of an UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643501/change-the-width-of-an-uibarbuttonitem/8652010#8652010) and [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image that just has the three lines - or rectangles. It should be pretty simple to design. You could even do it in Preview. `UIBarButtonItem` just uses the alpha channel.

Then `init` your `UIBarButtonItem` with custom image and it should look like that.

Comment: when i do that the image background is a different color and doesn't really blend into the navbar

Comment: Make sure the only alpha is the rectangles. The image background should be transparent. The nav bar will shine through as expected.

Comment: created the icon in preview and did as you said.  works great and thanks for your help =D